# Issue in passing data across php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am transferring data across php files.

index.php

```
<a href="sample.php?var=<?=$var?>" class="title">link</a>
```

sample.php

```
$var = $_GET['var'];
```

The problem is if `$var` includes `"` then it take data up to that only.

For eg

index.php

```
$var="Academic "Calendar" for Semester"; 
<a href="sample.php?var=<?=$var?>" class="title">link</a>
```

sample.php

```
$var = $_GET['var'];
```

In sample.php `$var=Academic`. It doesn't take the whole sentence. Because it takes `"` as closure of `<a href="` .

How to overcome this problem.

Comment: Are you really just asking how to URL encode strings so you can use them as querystrings ?

Comment: [rawurlencode](http://php.net/rawurlencode)

Comment: You should be getting a parse error with this. What do you want to do, have the quotes show up as quotes?

Comment: ^ it has to be `$var="Academic \"Calendar\" for Semester";`

Comment: @adeneo $var is taken from database so i can put backslash every time. Is their any other way

Comment: You mean to say that `Academic "Calendar" for Semester` is what the data is in your DB, exactly like that?

Comment: yeah and i want to print as it is

Comment: I don't think your `href` will work out. HTML source will reveal as `<a href="sample.php?var=Academic "Calendar" for Semester" class="title">link</a>`. You could try wrapping it in single quotes `$var='Academic "Calendar" for Semester';` but I can't see how that would work. You need to rethink this. What are those quotes doing in DB in the first place?

Comment: var =$number['desc'];     echo '<li><a href="desc.php?var=<?=<p><p>'.$var.'</p></p>?>">

Comment: actually those quotes are input and it can be anything

Comment: If you're getting the string from the DB with the doublequotes, that wouldn't be an issue, all you have to do is URL encode it and it will work just fine in the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

index.php

```
$var="Academic \"Calendar\" for Semester"; 
$var = urlencode($var);
<a href="sample.php?var=<?=$var?>" class="title">link</a>
```

This will automatically escape your string for parsing in a URL.

to use `"`  in a string you have to escape it with `\`.

Comment: This will cause a parse error. `$var="Academic "Calendar" for Semester";` - OP stated that quoted values are in DB.

Comment: Yes, of course, I didnt notice that, my answer has been updated. to use " in a string, while using " as a string delimiter, you have to escape the ". please check my updated answer :)

Comment: Yes I saw it, however when I asked the OP earlier about if `Academic "Calendar" for Semester` was the value in DB, OP said yes. Edit: scratch that lol OP accepted it. Good show ;-)

Comment: then the character has already been defined, and you dont need to worry about it, except using urlencode while creating the link. I guess this is only to make a variable work :)